# Uploading a file to S3 in laravel

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-4

I am using  larvel 4.2 and I have got these libraries added in my vendor folder. `aws-sdk-php` and `aws-sdk-php-laravel`.

When I try to upload a file in s3 bucket, it uploads a file of 45B only and the content of that file is a string specifying file location on file system. `$file` object is legit and it has been constructed using `$file = Input::file($field->element_name);`

```
    $s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'phxdevapp',
        'Key' => $file_new_name,
        'Body' => $file
));
```

Any pointers ?